# What hero-specific options are available, and what do they do?

Tags: overwatch

A few days ago when playing Mercy with a group of friends, someone told me that there is an option specific to Mercy to change from needing to hold down the mouse button to heal/damage boost to a toggle (click to turn on heals, click again to turn off).

What other hero-specific options are available, and what do they do?

Comment: Isn't this readily available by simply opening the Options menu?

Comment: I haven't actually been able to find the hero options for Widowmaker in the Options menu :(

Comment: Look at the options menu and read the options.

Comment: I don't have time to transcribe it, but if anyone wants to give a detailed answer to this question, everything you need is [in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRHRM-udywk).

Comment: @SaintWacko on the PC, go to Options, and then in the top-right corner select the hero. I had a hard time finding it too, until I noticed this.

Comment: One might downvote for lack of research, but that's not a close reason. I would say the most important option is turning on allied health bars for Soldier: 76. I sometimes get gold medals in healing with him after doing that. It's certainly not too broad, as most of the heroes don't even have these options.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer You're right, but because only a few of the twenty-one heroes have specific options and they're not all grouped together, it's a bit tedious to find them all, and you could overlook one trying.

Comment: @DavidS Oh! That is wonderful to hear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**D.Va** Has the option to switch between toggle or hold for her defense barrier.

**Genji** and **Hanzo** have options to auto climb walls themselves.

**Junkrat** has an option to have his riptire automatically climb walls.

**Lucio** has the option the toggle or hold shift to use the different auras

**Mercy** has the option to toggle or hold mouse buttons for healing. You can also change how guardian angel targeting works. By default you will fly to your beam target, but you can change it so that you can fly to whoever you are looking at.

**Reinhardt** has the option to toggle or hold to keep his shield up

**Soldier:76** has an option to show allied health bars. Also an option to toggle or hold for sprint.

**Widowmaker** has the option to toggle or hold right click to zoom. You can also change relative aim sensitivity while zoomed in.

**Zarya** has an option to show allied health bars.

Comment: There's no option for Soldier: 76's sprint, and you forgot one Mercy option.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer there used to be a sprint option, wonder why they took it out.

Comment: D.Va now has an option to change her barrier from toggle to hold.

Answer (score 3):

There are some but not all characters have hero specific options. To find these go to options, controls, and then at the top right select the hero under the "ALL HEROES" dropdown. These specific options are about half way down under the "HERO" heading. The different options include.

- Soldier 76: Allied health bars (Shows your allies health above their head, same as seen on support heroes)
- Zarya: Allied health bars (Same as support and Soldier 76's option)
- Widowmaker: Toggle zoom (Single click/tap alt fire instead of holding alt fire to zoom)
- Widowmaker: Relative aim sensitivity while zoomed (Adjust your zoomed in aim independently from standard sensitivity)
- Lucio: Hold to crossfade (Hold to switch to speed boost and let go to switch back to healing boost)
- Mercy: Toggle beam connection (Toggle on/off the healing/damage boost beams instead of holding fire)
- Mercy: Guardian Angel prefers beam target (Guardian Angel flight will only pull you towards who your beam is attached to if you have it attached)
- Reinhardt: Toggle barrier (single click/tap instead of holding for your barrier)
- Genji/Hanzo/Junkrat: Automatically climb walls (Climb up walls without holding jump (Junkrat can only do this with his Rip-tire))

As of right now those are the only heroes and options available.